# jQuery sends 2 requests for ntlm negotiation?

Tags: jquery, http, .net-4.0, fiddler, ntlm

I'm using jQuery ajax to call an Ashx handler which returns json objects.

My IIS server is configured to use NTLM (Windows authentication).

However, for each request (which I call **1 time**) - there are **more** than 1 requests in the log.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf2ps.jpg
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Question :

How can I convert it to a  **single** request / response ?

Comment: I think this is just how the NTLM challenge-response works. I have seen the same on our IIS proxy.

Comment: @leppie what do you wsay about this http://books.google.co.il/books?id=_Y0rWd-Q2xkC&pg=PA479&lpg=PA479&dq=%22This+mechanism+provides+transparency,+but+generates+an+extra+round+trip+with+each%22&source=bl&ots=R8DBUfUHXo&sig=yEOfJu91EusdKeJGZd0N-iX6fHY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7-fNT76vFIGu0QWwhrmODA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22This%20mechanism%20provides%20transparency%2C%20but%20generates%20an%20extra%20round%20trip%20with%20each%22&f=false ? how can we solve it in  header ?

Comment: What is the request type (`type` attribute) of ajax requests? is it GET or POST ? Did you try changing the request types ?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM its a post.... let me try chenage it.

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM still... also in get.

Comment: As @leppie stated, each request will have go through the authentication.BUT if authenticating/security API can distinguish the authenticated requests with some session key this wont happen.I believe that is how spring-security-api for KERBEROS/SPNEGO works. I am not sure if you have that control here.

Comment: BTW, did anything worked with `PreAuthenticate` header as given in your books reference?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM the book states for c# webclient. my call is from jquery. and i can add headers injquery also , but i dont know the value to send with this header.

Comment: From the same book, the value `PreAuthenticate`  must be set to `true`.Good luck.

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM let me check. thank you.:)

Comment: The original comment is correct; this is how NTLM works. NTLM is a connection-oriented authentication protocol which means that it can reuse a connection that has already been authenticated, but that's often disabled for POSTs.